# How to get the highest paid employee row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

A table consists of employee name, address, phone, department, salary:

How to get the **highest paid employee** row from each department?

I tried with

```
select dept, max(salary) from employee group by dept
```

but it gives only two columns. But I want to select an entire row. How to do it?

Alternatively how to add more columns to the result?

(I am using SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply need to join the query you currently have back to the employee table to get the full employee information.

```
select e.*
from employee e
inner join (select dept, max(salary) ms from employee group by dept) m
  on e.dept = m.dept and e.salary = m.ms
```

Comment: +1 From a business point of view, this is so good that If you have two highest paid (same salary) in the same department, both will be listed. Solutions using row_number() and partition will most likely ignore that.

Comment: If you're concerned about ties, don't use row_number(), but rank(). It's an easy fix and solutions using windowing functions tend to (but don't always) perform better.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT name,
       address,
       phone,
       department,
       salary,
       dept
FROM   (SELECT name,
               address,
               phone,
               department,
               salary,
               dept,
               row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rn
        FROM   employee) AS e
WHERE  e.rn = 1
```

Using row_number() will give you one row if there is a tie for the highest salary. If you want all the highest salaries for each department you should use rank() instead.

```
SELECT name,
       address,
       phone,
       department,
       salary,
       dept
FROM   (SELECT name,
               address,
               phone,
               department,
               salary,
               dept,
               rank() OVER(PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY salary DESC) AS rn
        FROM   employee) AS e
WHERE  e.rn = 1
```

Comment: Technically, I like you solution, but you missed the point: list highest paid employee of each department

Comment: @Adrian - Updated with version using rank() instead to include ties for the highest salary per department.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
select * from employee where salary = (select max(salary) from employee)
```

Comment: That will only retrieve the record of the single highest paid employee. OP wants a list of the highest paid in each department.

Comment: Why the -1.  It was not a clearly dangerous answer.  I give you +1 to get you back to even.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for this. This helped me. I want to get the highest-paid employee's name and his/her salary only. So my query is a bit different: 
select name, salary from XYZ where salary=(select max(salary) from xyz);

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as (
  select *, rank() over (partition by dept order by salary desc) as [r]
  from employees
)
select * from cte where [r] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employee 
where salary in
(select  max(salary) from employee group by dept);
```

Answer (score -1):

If situation like you have both employee details and department in same table and you have to find the highest paid employee from each department like given below

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName    Department     Salary
1            Neeraj         Dot Net        45000
2            Ankit          Java           5000
3            Akshay         Java           6000
4            Ramesh         Dot Net        7600
5            Vikas          Java           4000
7            Neha           Php            8500
8            Shivika        Php            4500
9            Tarun          Dot Net        9500
```

Then you can solve it by using below solutions

Solution - 1

```
SELECT t.EmployeeName,t.Department,t.Salary 
FROM(SELECT MAX(Salary) AS TotalSalary,Department FROM Employee GROUP BY Department) 
AS TempNew Inner Join Employee t ON TempNew.Department=t.Department  
and TempNew.TotalSalary=t.Salary 
ORDER BY t.Department ASC
```

Solution -2

```
;WITH EmployeeDetails AS (
SELECT EmployeeName, Department, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Department 
ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS SalaryRank, Salary FROM Employee )
SELECT EmployeeName, Department, Salary FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE SalaryRank=1
```

OUTPUT

```
EmployeeName    Department  Salary
Neeraj           Dot Net    45000
Akshay           Java       6000
Neha             Php        8500
```