# Query that brings the id of the employee with the highest salary in a function Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following problem:
I need to create a function PLSQL that takes a position as a parameter and returns the employee's highest salary id. If you have more than one, return the one with the most recent hire date.

```
EMP (table)
  empno (id)
  ename (employee name)
  job (occupation)
  mgr (boss id)
  hiredate (hiring date)
  sal (salary)
  comm (commission)
  depto (Department)
```

As I am new to SQL, I hope your help to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Initially it will be the entry of the job parameter (ex: Analyst) and will have to return the employee ID with the highest salary. Return example (empno: 2455).

If you have more than one employee, bring with the most recent hiring date, example: (3555 - 02/21/2020).

Comment: If you want to learn something you should try to write this function by yourself, not only copy-paste. Or at least search hundreds of similiar answers, like this: [How to get the highest paid employee row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262415/how-to-get-the-highest-paid-employee-row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL>   SELECT empno, ename, job, sal, hiredate
  2      FROM emp
  3  ORDER BY job, sal DESC, hiredate DESC;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000 09.12.82
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000 03.12.81
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1300 12.01.83  --> highest ranked CLERK
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300 23.01.82
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950 03.12.81
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            920 17.12.80
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975 02.04.81
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850 01.05.81
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450 09.06.81
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT      10000 17.11.81
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600 20.02.81  --> highest ranked SALESMAN
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500 08.09.81
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250 28.09.81
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250 22.02.81

14 rows selected.
```

Function: uses `row_number` analytic function to *sort* employees per their salary and hire date. Code contains some superfluous data, but it'll help if you want to use its `select` separately, to see what's going on.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sal (par_job IN emp.job%TYPE)
  2     RETURN emp.empno%TYPE
  3  IS
  4     retval  emp.empno%TYPE;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT empno
  7       INTO retval
  8       FROM (SELECT empno,
  9                    ename,
 10                    job,
 11                    sal,
 12                    hiredate,
 13                    ROW_NUMBER ()
 14                       OVER (PARTITION BY job ORDER BY sal DESC, hiredate DESC)
 15                       rn
 16               FROM emp
 17              WHERE job = par_job)
 18      WHERE rn = 1;
 19
 20     RETURN retval;
 21  EXCEPTION
 22     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 23     THEN
 24        RETURN NULL;
 25  END;
 26  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_sal ('CLERK') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
      7876

SQL> SELECT f_sal ('SALESMAN') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
      7499

SQL> SELECT f_sal ('hotfix') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------


SQL>
```

Comment: what is about no_data_found? :)

Comment: Data will always be found, @hotfix. At least, in my universe (represented by this example) :)

Comment: i mean if you call a function with not existing job

Comment: I know what you meant, @hotfix; just kidding. Thank you for the comment, I modified function code.